# How do you know if a function is asynchronous or synchronous in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to know if a function is asynchronous or synchronous in node.js ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function will be executed asynchronously if it does any I/O(network,filesystem etc) activity, otherwise it  is synchronous

Answer (score 3):

There's no programmatic way to tell.

The reliable way is to read the documentation.

You can also try to infer it from the function accepting a callback (but that isn't reliable, see `Array.prototype.forEach` for an example of a synchronous function that accepts a callback).

Answer (score 2):

You can guess by the function profile. But you can't be really sure. For example if a function ask a callback in a parameter or if it returns a promise, it's probably asynchronous.

But you have no way to be sure. A function can ask a callback and do a synchronous work. It can even returns a promise and still be synchronous.

You have to read the documentation to be sure.